# multiple call of print in function failed

Tags: assembly, winapi, x86-64, nasm, msvcrt

I want to call two simple function(fun1 and fun2) consecutively, but it seems that only fun1 is executed. Do I need to save/load register before/after the call? (I'm working on windows 10 64bit)

result:

```
hello 1
hello 2
test 1
```

code:

```
segment .data
    hello1 db "hello 1", 0xd, 0xa, 0
    hello2 db "hello 2", 0xd, 0xa, 0
    test1 db "test 1", 0xd, 0xa, 0
    test2 db "test 2", 0xd, 0xa, 0

segment .text
global main
extern ExitProcess
extern printf

main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32

    ; Call printf to print the main message
    lea     rcx, [hello1]
    call    printf

    lea     rcx, [hello2]
    call    printf

    call    fun1

    call    fun2

    ; Exit the program
    xor     rax, rax
    call    ExitProcess

; Define additional functions
section .text
fun1:
    lea     rcx, [test1]
    call    printf

    ret

fun2:
    lea     rcx, [test2]
    call    printf

    ret
```

command:

```
nasm -f win64 -g -o main.o main.s
link /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO main.o kernel32.lib kernel32legacylib.lib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib ucrt.lib /subsystem:console /entry:main /out:main.exe /DEBUG
```

Thanks so much for the help from the comments, now I'm learning to reserve space in the function/procedure and it works.

**updated code**:

```
segment .data
    hello1 db "hello 1", 0xd, 0xa, 0
    hello2 db "hello 2", 0xd, 0xa, 0
    test1 db "test 1", 0xd, 0xa, 0
    test2 db "test 2", 0xd, 0xa, 0

segment .text
global main
extern ExitProcess
extern printf

main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32

    ; Call printf to print the main message
    lea     rcx, [hello1]
    call    printf

    lea     rcx, [hello2]
    call    printf

    call    fun1

    call    fun2

    ; Exit the program
    xor     rax, rax
    call    ExitProcess

; Define additional functions
section .text
fun1:
    sub     rsp, 32       ; Allocate
    lea     rcx, [test1]
    call    printf
    add     rsp, 32       ; Deallocate

    ret

fun2:
    sub     rsp, 32       ; Allocate
    lea     rcx, [test2]
    call    printf
    add     rsp, 32       ; Deallocate

    ret
```

result now:

```
hello 1
hello 2
test 1
test 2
```

Comment: please always tag the correct architecture for assembly questions

Comment: Run `x64dbg.exe main.exe`, step over calls and watch `rsp`.  BTW the exit code at `call ExitProcess` is expected in `rcx` and not in `eax`.

Comment: `fun1` and `fun2` do not align the stack to a 16 byte boundary, nor do either of those functions create 32 bytes of shadow space. I can only guess that `fun1` doesn't properly return because the stack was clobbered by the call to `printf` in `fun1`

Comment: `fun1` and `fun2` should be doing `sub rsp, 40` to realign the stack by 16 before another call as well as reserve shadow space.  Unlike `main`, they're not doing a `push rbp` which moves the stack by 8.  It seems Windows `printf` happens to work even with the stack misaligned, unlike GNU/Linux scanf and printf where you'd get a segfault inside the library function as it used `movaps` or `movdqa` to copy some stack memory.